# Visibily rules on webform in panel

Tags: webforms, panels

I have the following issue using a [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) inside a `panels-page`. I have the following configuration:

I have a pretty simple `contact form` (to start with) build with webforms. In this form is a field `emailaddress` which is filled with the content of a field in the `node` on which the webform is placed using panels.

For using the `nodefield` as `content` in my form I am using the module `webform_node_value`. In this way I can use one form dynamically on (lets say) profile pages. These profile page are normal nodes and are not using the module profiles.

On the panel configuration I am using a context to concatenate the `node-field`.

This configuration is working without any problems.

The problem:
When I put a Visibility rule on the webform pane in the panel, which is checking if the context exists

(1) or a rule which checks if the field emailadres is not empty

(2), these rules are not working.
Using rule 1 (context) the form is always hidden... Using rule 2 (empty field) the form is always visible...

I tried to use the form as a Webform or as a block. I am out of options...

Anybody any idea what's going wrong?